# Where is the .bashrc file on Windows? (Daniel Kehoe's learn-rails tutorial book)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-editor, railsapps

I previously asked a similar question with regards to cloud9, but I am now trying to do the same project in parallel on my windows 10 machine because I will not have internet access to use cloud9. I am trying to set up the configuration in preparation for following Daniel Kehoe's learn-rails tutorial book, but I am having trouble setting up the environment variables. The book seems to explain how to do it on Mac but I can not find the file in the atom editor. the book says to type the command:

```
atom ~/.bash_profile
```

However this just creates a new file that is not part of my rails app project directory. i have also tried

```
atom ~/.bashrc
```

which is the alternative but with the same result. It just creates a file unrelated to my project. The file is supposed to already exist somewhere.

I am supposed to put the environment variables into a file called ".bashrc" but I don't know where to find this file as it is hidden.  How can I locate and open this file with Atom text editor?

Comment: Really, don't try to follow my Learn Ruby on Rails book with Windows. Save yourself the headache. The book is written for macOS or Linux. There are no ENV variables or .bash_profile file on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

`.bashrc` , `.bash_profile` are used in unix based operating systems for the terminal. In windows you set environment variables differently. In windows 10, search for environment variables in start menu, and select `Edit the system environment variables` and set them from there.

PS: You can have `.bashrc` if you have installed something like git bash, cygwin bash or bash for windows 10 or something else. And all 3 handle `.bashrc` differently.

Comment: Perhaps an old answer. As of today, creating a .bashrc in your ~ directory of windows git bash seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Typing `echo ~` in the Git Bash terminal will tell you where that folder is which contains the `.bashrc` file